# How Can I Enable Editing for User Information AD Properties?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory

In a list, I have a column for users.  When I click on the username it opens up the user profile panel with information gotten from AD for that user.  This is good.

You would think that if I clicked on "Edit Item" of a user's profile that I would get that user's profile, and be able to edit it.  Actually, when I pull up the "Edit Personal Settings" panel (by clicking on "Edit Item" in "User Information" accessible through the welcome dropdown button), the little panel flashes almost like it was going to show me another tab, then that extra tab disappears.

Now, I don't want to use mysites at all (my users don't need special profiles).  I want everything to work through AD only, and use that "Edit Item" panel - like it did in Sharepoint Services 2007.

What am I missing, and how do I get it to work the right way?

[about two weeks later...]
I am still stuck here.  Anybody have a clue for me?
Aside from the UPS thing, the question to answer is how to get the "Edit Item" panel to display items for editing!

Comment: hmmm, most likely problem with custom code which is been deployed as event receiver for that specific list for "Updating List Item", if you got any custom List event defined for this specific list ?

Comment: For this list I have no custom code at all.  In fact, I just created the list by "Create site based on external data" - ie, an excel table.

Comment: very strange, is there any chance you can create another test account in AD and test same scenario with that account and see if it does the same thing, if it does then it probably be a bug in code, that only let yu edit your profile even if you want to edit someone's else.
correct me am wrong please :)

Comment: Okay, with another admin user (only they could get edit rights you know), it opens the right user when I click "Edit Item".  However, the only thing I can edit in that panel is "Delete User from Collection" - I can't even see the other account settings for that user except the username.  I am using an admin account with full rights.  But in the "View Item", I can see everything.

Comment: Well, I am looking now in SCA, and I see that whenever I click on any of the links under "Manage Profile Service/Sharepoint User Profile Service Applicaion", such as "Synchronization", "Organizations" or "People" I get an error page.

Comment: click on any of the links under "Manage Profile Service/Sharepoint User Profile Service Applicaion", such as "Synchronization", "Organizations" or "People" I get an error page.  Now, I can confirm that the User Profile Service Application IS running. However, in miisclient UI, I can see that the FULL IMPORT fails each time because replication access was denied (bingo on the sync service!) - maybe that will fix it.

Comment: let us know if you fixed it then :) if not what error you getting on error page

Comment: Okay, I got the user synchronization working, but it still doesn't let me edit the profile details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UPS is set up correctly, and mysites is set up correctly, when the user clicks on their username anywhere (say, in a username column), it will take them directly to that person's profile page on mysites.

With that said, the only time you will get the profile to load NOT in mysites is if the user has not yet been synchronized from AD to Sharepoint (this timing depends on the service settings in SCA).

A user may also get the NOT-mysites-profile page by clicking on their name in the welcome button (top right-hand corner) and choosing "My Settings" from that menu.

Whether a person can edit a profile in mysites depends on their level of permissions on mysites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to SP using that user profile in question.
2. Change something in the site.
3. Log out.

Can you edit the profile information for that user now?

Comment: No.  However, ALL the profiles are in question here.  I, even as admin, only see their profile properties in the "view", and don't see any of them in "edit" mode.  And none of them ever get updated.  I have a related thread here:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40392/user-profiles-user-information-vs-mysites

Comment: Try the above steps. Pick a user (user X). On the top right corner. Log as user X. Edit something. Log back in with your credentials. Can you update the user X UP information.

Comment: When you manage user permissions using AD groups, individual user profiles are not expanded until that individual user makes a change in SP. You can verify this by using the steps above. If you still cannot edit the user profile information then you have some other issues.

Comment: I said, "no", I can't edit the profile information.  I logged in as testuser, added something to a list, logged out.  Then I logged in as me and clicked on his name in a list where users are listed and none of his specs from AD show in the profile report, even though I know they are really there.  When I go from the profile report to "Edit Profile", the only thing that shows is the account login name.  In AD, that account has had details for a long time.  I even tried adding new ones.  I also made sure the fields are linked in SCA.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the "no" :) I am guessing then the UPS application is not pulling all the AD information. Someone with UPS application expertise can answer that.

Comment: Well, the UPS thing is only half the problem.  The other half is actually what the question is about - that I don't even get any fields in the "edit" panel.  That's really what I want to solve in this question.

Comment: I fixed the UPS problem (you can see my post here:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40392/user-profiles-user-information-vs-mysites/47740#47740).