# User Profiles "User Information" -vs- Mysites

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

In Sharepoint lists, where it gives you a link to the user who created or modified a file, or to a username specified in a "user field" on a list, sometimes I get a plain "Edit User Profile" panel, and sometimes I end up at mysites.

Why?  And how do I standardize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user's AD account profile has never been synchronized to sharepoint, then, when you view a user's profile, it will pull info from AD and show you a simple in-page profile report.  If, however, the user's profile has been scynchronized properly, you will be taken to mysites instead.

Note that the AD profiles won't synchronize to sharepoint if you point your USP service to an AD group.  In order for synchronization to work, you have to point your USP service to an OU with users, not a security group.  Sharepoint will not synchronize user profiles based on users added to a security group.  It only synchronizes with user accounts directly inside of an OU.

Thus, to standardize things, either make sure the USP service works and all your user accounts in AD are synchronizable, OR disable mysites completely.

Answer (score 1):

Are you utilizing OOTB functionality or custom code on the particular location? We had a custom redirect that forced users to non my sites profile pages, which I had to fix when we started to use my sites.

Also, are the users active users? Or deleted?

This behavior shouldn't occur OOTB.

If the user does not have a mysite account, by default it should auto-create one for the user the first time they visit the page.

Comment: No, I have no custom code to that regard.  Yes, the users are all active.  And the users have not visited their mysites page.  Likewise, if the user goes to "My Settings" in the little button menu at the top-right, it shows a sharepoint popup with the user information instead of a mysites link.

Comment: Basically, there is a page in the _layouts folder called userdisp.aspx that determines where to go when a user's name is clicked, the following is worth a read http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/lkuhn/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=47. Alternatively, I'll post some custom code I wrote later today that'll do exactly what you need, as I wrote it for my company's SharePoint environment.

Comment: You are very kind, thank you very much.  I will look for your assistance!

Comment: Will it make any difference if I only use AD groups instead of individual AD users?

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer not to use mysites, because users will have to login *again* to view profiles - it is a separate site.

Comment: Actually, they shouldn't have to log in again, as it is just another web application on the same server. So you have a couple options, either disable MySites in Central Administration, or.... you can utilize the code snippet for mysite redirection in a custom solution.

Comment: If I disable mysites in SCA, will it actually load the user profiles from AD, or will it mess up anything?

Comment: I agree, I shouldn't have to log in again, but I do!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have all user links bring users to My Sites, you can start off creating the user control, by the following code on http://blogs.sharepointguys.com/brendon/sharepoint-2007/programming/redirect-to-your-own-mysite-landing-page/ and then in the RedirectIfNecessary(SPListItem user) you can utilize the following code.

```
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                SPSite _site = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPServiceContext _serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(_site);
                UserProfileManager _userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(_serviceContext);
                string _mySiteUrl = _userProfileManager.MySiteHostUrl;
                string _profileUrl = string.Empty;
                int userID = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(), out userID))
                {
                    SPUser profileUser = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUsers.GetByID(userID);
                    if (_userProfileManager.UserExists(profileUser.LoginName))
                    {
                        UserProfile _userProfile = _userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(profileUser.LoginName);
                        _profileUrl = _userProfile.PublicUrl.AbsoluteUri;
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        _profileUrl = String.Format("{0}Person.aspx?accountname={1}", _mySiteUrl, profileUser.LoginName);
                    }

                    SPUtility.Redirect(_profileUrl, SPRedirectFlags.Static, this.Context);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I found the solution.  Please see my answer.